# Можно ли сделать face detection с нуля без opencv в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я бы хотел узнать можно ли сделать face detection с нуля без opencv в python? Без использования tensorflow и библиотек нейросетей.

Comment: Да запросто! Только надо сначала написать собственные аналоги openCV или TF... но смысл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если задуматься, то все названные вами модули создавались людьми и чисто теоретически можно написать все с нуля. Вопрос в том сколько это у вас займет времени и что получится в итоге.

Представьте себе, что кто-то захочет создать космический корабль с нуля, не используя готовые детали. Вероятность успеха будет стремиться к нулю, но возможно найдется такой гений, у которого это получится. Ваш вопрос натолкнул меня на эту аналогию. ;)